# SQLAlchemy: directed relationships within triads

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Given users and directed relationships between them:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    follows = relationship(
        'User', secondary='following',
        primaryjoin=(Following.follower_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(Following.followee_id == id)
    )
    followed_by = relationship(
        'User', secondary='following',
        primaryjoin=(Following.followee_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(Following.follower_id == id)
    )

class Following(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'following'
    follower_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    followee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
```

I need to use SQLAlchemy to select triads of users such as:

```
A follows B
B follows A
A follows C
C follows B
```

I can't figure out how to use `exists()` to select bidirectional relationships in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using multiple inner `JOIN`s on the required relationships (table `Following`) you can achieve this in a rather straightforward way:

```
# create aliases for each pair of relations that must exist
AB = aliased(Following)
BA = aliased(Following)
AC = aliased(Following)
CB = aliased(Following)
CA = aliased(Following)

triads = (
    session.query(
        AB.follower_id.label("a_id"),
        AB.followee_id.label("b_id"),
        AC.followee_id.label("c_id"),
    )
    # .select_from(AB)  # @note: this is implied, so not really required
    .join(BA, and_(AB.followee_id == BA.follower_id,
                   AB.follower_id == BA.followee_id))
    .join(AC, AB.follower_id == AC.follower_id)
    .join(CB, and_(AC.followee_id == CB.follower_id,
                   AB.followee_id == CB.followee_id))
    # exclude C following A using LEFT JOIN + WHERE IS NULL)
    .outerjoin(CA, and_(AC.followee_id == CA.follower_id,
                        AC.follower_id == CA.followee_id))
    .filter(CA.follower_id == None)
)

for a, b, c in triads:
    print(a, b, c)
```

This probably would not be as robust if `User` can follow him/herself, in which case one can exclude such cases with additional `where` clauses.

*Option-2:* Another clean (very readable) way to do this would be to ensure that actual relationships exist, but the `SQL` statement generated by the code below is probably an overkill to achieve the desired result:

```
# create aliases for each assumed user (A, B, C)
A = aliased(User)
B = aliased(User)
C = aliased(User)
# also aliases to navigate relationship and check same user
Aa = aliased(User)
Bb = aliased(User)

triads = (
    session.query(A, B, C)
    .join(B, A.follows)  # A follows B
    .join(Aa, B.follows).filter(Aa.id == A.id)  # B follows Aa (same as A)
    .join(C, A.follows)  # A follows C
    .join(Bb, C.follows).filter(Bb.id == B.id)  # C follows Bb (same as B)
    .filter(~C.follows.any(User.id == A.id))  # exclude C following A
)

for a, b, c in triads:
    print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: I also need to exclude C following A and B following C. This has to be the exact triad I mentioned.

Comment: I see. Updated the answer for both options to exclude `C->A`

Comment: Do I have a quarantee that the triads will be unique? That is, that I don't get (A, B, C) and (B, A, C) etc.? I am not really good with JOINs and I can't see how it would happen here.

Comment: All right, I figured it out myself with .filter(and_(AB.follower_id < AB.followee_id, AB.followee_id < AC.followee_id)) before the first join. Cheers!

Comment: Great! Although I think that the exclusion of `C->A` should prevent non-uniqueness already, doesn't it?